# Get newly created id inside laravel 'created' event

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-events

I am using laravel **created** event. I want to use newly created id in another table. But when i print created object, i don't get the id property. How can i get newly created id in **created** event.

This is my code.

```
public static function booted()
{
    static::created(function ($agentTask)
    {
        echo $agentTask->id;
        print_r($agentTask);
    });
}
```

echo statement printing null. and when i print $agentTask object, i don't find id anywhere.

Comment: Did you try to use the `boot` method instead of `booted`?

Comment: Also, if @Rolf 's suggestion does not work for you please provide dd($agentTask).

Comment: @Rolf, i tried `boot` as well. But still same issue.

Comment: @Kurt, this is what $agentTask printing in json `{"task_id":1,"lead_id":128,"agent_id":1,"started_at":"2020-07-22T09:15:09.429577Z"}`

Comment: @subhankhalid What is the model you are using this created event on?

Comment: @Kurt I am using `AgentTask` model. And it is Pivot

Comment: it looks like your pivot table does not have `id` column at all. So what are you actually trying to get from it?

Comment: @anuj it has id column as primary key brother.

Comment: I just checked on my local application and it is returning me  `id`. How is the create method is fired?

Comment: create method is firing using lighthouse.

Comment: @ Anuj creating event is working fine. but created event doesn't have id in object

Comment: @subhankhalid, can you access the `id` attribute by using `$agentTask->pivot->id`?

Answer (score 0):

it should be `boot` not `booted`

```
public static function boot()
```

`booted` is used to perform any actions required after the model boots.

while `boot` is used to bootstrap the model and its traits.

Laravel API DOC: [booted()](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_booted) [boot()](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_boot)

Comment: I used `boot` but issue is still same